# Android Studio not showing Version control option

Tags: android, android-studio, version-control

Its really freaking me out. I cannot find the Version Control option anywhere in the android studio not even in Settings. Attaching Images below please help me.

I didn't find anything related to this, everyone is just saying to enable version control from the VCS option, which doesn't exist here.

Android Studio Version: 3.5.1

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you initialized git in your project with this command git init?

Comment: @mamunmohamed Yes, I did init the git but still not getting any menus.

Comment: I finally got this to work after resetting the android studio setting by deleting .AndroidStudio3.5 folder from the user.